# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification called twice if screen rotates

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsnotificationcenter

I create notifications when the keyboard appears and disappears.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Creates notification when keyboard appears and disappears
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.adjustingHeight(true, notification: notification)

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.adjustingHeight(false, notification: notification)

}

private func adjustingHeight(show: Bool, notification: NSNotification) {

    // Gets notification information in an dictionary
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    // From information dictionary gets keyboard’s size
    let keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    // Gets the time required for keyboard pop up animation
    let animationDurarion = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSTimeInterval
    // Animation moving constraint at same speed of moving keyboard & change bottom constraint accordingly.
    if !(show && self.bottomConstraint.constant != self.bottomConstraintConstantDefault) {
        if show {
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = (CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame) + self.bottomConstraintConstantDefault / 2)
        } else {
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = self.bottomConstraintConstantDefault
        }
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDurarion) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    self.hideLogoIfSmall()

}
```

The strange behaviour occurs when the keyboard is already shown and I rotate the screen. Then the next actions occurs:

1. UIKeyboardWillHideNotification called
2. UIKeyboardWillShowNotification called (with the old height of the keyboard)
3. UIKeyboardWillShowNotification called (with the new height of the keyboard)

The result of this is that my view is not updated properly because the first time UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is called I receive a different height of the keyboard than the second time.

Comment: This is normal behavior as the keboard goes down before it rotates and up again after the rotation. The height after the rotation may be different so you should update your code according to the new height.

Comment: @HannesSverrisson so you mentioned only one down and one up, or did you mean one dow and two up? Thanks!

Comment: @HannesSverrisson because the behaviour for me are one down and two up

Comment: @WillM. the behaviour I found is the below: I have my device in portrait and the keyboard already shown. Then I rotate the device and after that the keyboard go down and then go up twice.

Comment: @angeldev most likely unrelated, but you are setting up your observers in an odd way. You are creating them in `viewDidLoad` but removing them in `viewDidDisappear`. If you are going to remove them in `viewDidDisappear` you should create them in `viewDidAppear`, or if you are going to create them in `viewDidLoad`, you should remove them in `deinit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. When I get `keyboardFrame`, I was using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` which returns the frame of the keyboard before the animation begins. The correct way of do that is with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`which returns the frame of the keyboard after the animation has completed.

```
let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
```

Now `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is called twice but returns the same height of the keyboard in both calls.